# Importing a specific mailbox from exchange account to excel using power query

Tags: excel, exchange-server, powerbi, powerquery

I have a query which takes all emails from a shared mailbox exchange account and parses them. However the account has two folders: Inbox and Archive. The Archive folder contains more than 14,000 emails and is not necessary as the parse filters them out anyway.

Is there a way to only import the Inbox folder, rather than power query loading all 14,000 emails and then filtering them out?

Also, it is not feasible to delete the Archive folder.

Comment: just as an idea: "configure a 2nd account which has only access to the mailox" Will that work for you?

Comment: Good idea, however i'm not sure how to do this as the mailbox is a shared mailbox (oops forgot to mention, sorry).

Answer (score 0):

I do not know your "Excel" solution however I think that (as mentioned in the comments) you could create a 2nd account and then grant the account only access to the inbox folder and not to others.

[image]

[image]